# Can I cancel auto insurance for the car at home while travelling abroad?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

I am a resident of North Carolina and will be travelling outside US for a few months. Thus I will not be driving my car while gone. I'll either leave the car in a garage for storage or leave it for my cousin to drive. In either case, can I stop my car insurance and resume it after I come back to US?

Comment: DId you try calling your insurance agent?

Comment: If you have a lien on the car, you probably can't cancel the insurance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

I have done this frequently (with AAA), however it's not quite a full cancel, as you would probably want to leave insurance against theft/flood/etc. (will be required if you don't own your car outright) but it will drastically reduce the rate.

There are also two "flavors" of doing it, you can tell them until when, or you can leave it at "until you inform them otherwise", which will typically end up with you paying less right now but an equivalent amount as the other option by the end of the year/term.

Also plan on the insurance only being able to be changed on a work day, i.e. if you return Saturday, and plan to drive Sunday, have it with driving insurance on Friday (or see if you can schedule it for Sunday).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is helpful. Paying insurance against theft/flood if my car is stored in a garage make sense. Though I am still slightly confused about the other option. If I leave my car with my cousin, he'll have to include the car under his insurance plan. In such a scenario I believe I should be able to cancel my insurance completely since having two insurance by two different people on the same car doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Having some coverage even when the car is in the possession of your relative would be a good idea, especially if their coverage isn't a good as yours. You also might have to provide proof of insurance to the lender if you have a loan.

Comment: @AbbyJ I would check with the insurance company, but I don't think that they will be able to insure it without you giving the car (title transfer) to them, AND had them store it (i.e. not at your address)  - and even if you did, then their insurance would increase a proportional amount, similar to how much you would be saving.

Comment: @user2813274: I don't think you would necessarily need to transfer title.  In the past, I've taken out an insurance policy in my name on a car I didn't own.  The insurance company didn't mind at all.